# Sqlite Concept during opening and closing of an Application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have tried different tutorials implementing basic CRUDS in sqlite database. But I am missing the basic concepts on how sqlite is being created and used when an application is running. I just implemented codes without understanding the basics and I guess this goes for every beginner. I tried different keywords in finding the answer but seems I can't find the real basics. You may think that I didn't research enough, but most of the discussions involve sqlite's definition and samples codes. I you don't mind please share your understanding on sqlite.

1. Every time you open the application, what happens to the sqlite?
2. When the user resumes the app, what happens to sqlite?
3. The real reason in closing sqlite connection, does this affect the application?
4. For example the apps menu is dynamically created from sqlite database(the database data is from another external database mysql), does this slows the the application?

*sigh noobness here. Thanks.

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Additional codes:

```
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (isFinishing()) {
            mCursor.close();
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCursor.close();
    }
```

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Everytime you open an application, nothing is done with the SQLite database. Something only happens if you make a reference to it and use getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase.
- Again, nothing happens here either. SQLite should be used in a way that its opened, query is ran, and closed. This keeps the database from being locked by a thread while another thread tries to use it.
- You close the sqlite connection to free up the thread and take the lock off the database. If you try to use two seperate sqlite helpers at the same time, you will get a locked database error as only 1 thread can access a database at a time. You dont want to keep that connection open.
- The SQLite database should not slow an app at all. You cannot use it as an enterprise level database (just doesnt have the functionality). You can run as many queries as you like, as it only uses 1 thread, and as long as the results are not huge you should not have a performance problem.